# how to set border for label for ie8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, label, border

In HTML, how to set border for label for ie8?

```
 <div id="childDivId" style="width: 28em; color: gray; font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 27.5em; padding-left: 2em;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);/* for ie8 */">

  <label id="savedDataLbl" style="cursor: pointer;"  onclick="setSavedData()">
     Saved Data
  </label>
   | 
   <label id="searchResultsLbl" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="setSearchResults()">        
    Search Results
   </label>
</div>
```

Without jQuery.

Comment: That’s an odd use of `label` elements. By the specs, they should be labels for form controls, not controls themselves.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about adding a border to the `label` element, you can do that with CSS:

```
label {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Sorry pal, it isn't yet hosted on the main site. I'm trying locally. Actually, I want to set border for two selected labels.

Comment: @VinodKumar, if it does not work, then the problem is in the part of your code that you did not disclose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <label id="savedDataLbl" style="cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid red;"  onclick="setSavedData()">
```

Also add some `padding-bottom` to your div.

It's visible in IE8!